# center image vertically inside a smaller div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic page, the image loaded could be larger than the div or smaller than the div.
The div is 100% width and 105px height.

I need the image to fill the entire div all the time.
If the image is bigger i need it to keep its aspect ratio and just the center part of the image be shown. How can i do this?

```
<div class="image-container info-container-area " style="">
    <div class="info-area">
        <div class="image-wrapper" style="height: 105px;">
            <img src="image.jpg" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use image as background and set background-size:cover

Comment: page is cms controlled and clients can enter images into these set areas and they adjust to size and ratio depending on screen size, but in mobile format they want the divs to be 105px height and full width and the images to fill that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/LLCNs/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Most Outer Div Style CSS as below. Seems your outer div class `class="info-area"`.

```
 display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: the image still squashes and not set to its orginal size

Comment: can you share page link?

Comment: OK, try one more change for img tag css. put style="max-height:105px"

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `width:inherit; height:inherit;` for `img` tag

Comment: sorry nothign happend

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if my example it helps you...
you can try my example

[http://jsfiddle.net/Ouali/YT85P/3/][1]